# Javascript - Parse - Cloud Code - beforeSave and afterSave

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Does beforeSave and afterSave run when files are edited by the administrator in the data browser? Or only when a file is created and saved within an app? Reason I'm wondering is because when I'm changing some column information within an already saved object, I'm getting the error message: "Error: success/error was not called". It would be extremely undesirable for the beforeSave and afterSave methods to run when objects are simply being edited after the fact by an administrator, so I really hope this is not the case.

Thanks if anyone has input.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the beforeSave and afterSave triggers are called both when the object is created and when it's modified. Take look at the `existed()` function.

```
if(!request.object.existed())
     //is a first-save

} else {
    //just an update

}
```

Here the [official reference](https://www.parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Object.html#methods_existed).

Comment: Note that existed() works with beforeSave but it won't work with afterSave. Even for newly-created objects, it returns true inside a trigger function. (I don't see this documented anywhere but I just tested the behavior.)